# Raphael.js 2.0.0 drag&drop image in IE8 not working(vml)

Tags: svg, raphael, vml

I am using the rapahel version 2.0.0 and for some reason the image is
not being dragged in IE8(start and move get fired but the image is not
moving)there is no exceptions nor errors...
and I tried using the 1.5.2 it works but than I dont have the
onDragOver and snapTo methods and I need this 2 methods!!!

Does any one have the same problem and a solution to this???

here is the code:

```
var start = function () {
   this.onDragOver(function(event){
   this.animate({"x":Raphael.snapTo(this.attr("x"), event.attr("x")
+3, 1), "y":Raphael.snapTo(this.attr("y"), event.attr("y")+3, 1)},
100);
   if(event.data("bin") == 1){this.animate({"opacity": 0.1}, 1000,
function(){this.remove();});}
});
  this.ox = this.type == "rect" || this.type == "image" ?
this.attr("x") : this.attr("cx");
  this.oy = this.type == "rect" || this.type == "image" ?
this.attr("y") : this.attr("cy");
  this.attr({cursor: "move"});
  this.toFront();
};
var move = function (dx, dy) {
       this.attr(this.type=="rect" || this.type == "image" ?{x: this.ox +
dx, y: this.oy + dy}:{cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
};
var end = function () {
    //this.animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 500);
};

var width = 800, height = 450;
var paper = Raphael("canvas", width, height);
var lbl1 = paper.image("img/label.png", 10, 40, 100, 22);
lbl1.drag(move, start, end);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's fixed, just get a new copy of the raphael.js v2beta...Dmitry updated it!

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed, just get a new copy of the raphael.js v2beta...Dmitry updated it! 
https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/2.0